# Android database externally predefined

Tags: android, database

How can I build a timetable application in ANDROID which can access a database which is externally created in SQLite manager WITHOUT Internet..

Comment: You can use an embedded SQLite database

Comment: That's fine...still I'm trying to know how to use them in the application

Comment: Where is your data stored?

Comment: It's defined in my pc...

Comment: Put the database in you assets folder and you can use the following library: [Android SQlite Asset Helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

Comment: Oh!!It would be a great favour if you send me a basic code structure in android sqlite asset helper